# Is there a response to kochirakoso?

Tags: words

I respond to kochirakoso with doumo. Is this appropriate or necessary?　What is the correct response? A dialogue starts with ohayou x 2 yoroshiku onegaishimasu x 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No response is needed, but doumo is not bad per se.

https://www.japaneseforbeginners.info/2016/01/doumo.html

kochirakoso is the other speaker saying "from me, as well" (usually thank you or sorry, depending on context) so they have literally responded to something you've just said, and don't really expect you to respond to their response, it'd be like and endless chain of "sorry" "no, sorry" "no, sorry"

Just continue the flow of the conversation, and you'll be fulfilling their expectations. Though again, doumo is not a "wrong" thing to say there, just not needed really.